# Java generics type erasure

Tags: java, generics, erasure

I'd like to ask about java type erasure rules.

If we have classes:

```
public class Shape{}
public class Circle extends Shape{}


public class Base<T extends Shape>{
    T x;
    public void setX(T t){}
}

public class MainClass(){
    public static void main(String... _arg){
         Base<? extends Shape> bs = new Base<Circle>(); 
         bs.setX(new Circle()); // <- compilation problem
    }
}
```

Can you please explain me why calling setX() method causes compilation problem?

Comment: `? super Shape` would work there. "Producer Extends, Consumer Super"

Comment: @MichaelMyers: Au contraire: http://ideone.com/TYr10C.  `Base<? super Shape>` accepts a `Base` of any *supertype* of `Shape`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the compiler doesn't know that `new Circle` is valid.  Consider this code:

```
Base<? extends Shape> bs = new Base<Square>();  // Really a Base<Square> 
bs.setX(new Circle());
```

(FYI, a very similar example is given in the [Java tutorial on wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).)

You may now exclaim "But the compiler can see it's really a `Base<Square>`!".  But not in general.  Consider this:

```
Base<? extends Shape> bs = someInterface.getBaseOfSomeKindOfShape();
bs.setX(new Circle());
```

Comment: +1 Or `(Math.random() > .5) ? new Base<Square>() : new Base<Circle>()`. No way the compiler can figure that one out.